# Develop the Taylor Series for the function $f(x)={\frac{1}{1+x^2}}-{\frac{1}{x+2}}$ for $x=a$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Develop the Taylor Series for the function $$f(x)={\frac{1}{1+x^2}}-{\frac{1}{x+2}}$$ for $x=a$ and $a=0$
Do I have to take the derivative of both of those fractions? Or for $f_1(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, can I use the ratio $-x^2$ and use the geometric series resulting this $f_1(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\sum_{n\ge0}{(-1)^nx^{2n}}$ ?
With this being the formula for Taylor Series:
$$T_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}(x-a)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Expansion for $$\frac1{1+x^2}=\frac1{1-(-x^2)}=1-x^2+x^4-x^6...=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(-x^2\right)^k$$
The Expansion for $$\frac1{2+x}=\frac12*\frac1{1-(-\frac x2)}=\frac12\left(1-\left(\frac x2\right)+\left(\frac x2\right)^2-\left(\frac x2\right)^3...\right)=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(-\frac x 2\right)^k$$ You can just combine like terms and subtract them.

Comment: :P Beat me to it.

Comment: beat me too :p !

Comment: I rly don't get this exercise, can you tell me the final form for taylor series? I got $\sum_{n\ge1}{(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x}{2})^n}{n!}x^n}$

Comment: This doesn't use the derivative, this uses the geometric expansion of the series. Both are equivalent, but this one is much easier to derive.

Comment: Ok, so I just use the expansion of the series in Taylor formula, and get his series?

Comment: @NeacsuMihai If you use my series, you should end up getting the Taylor Series, as they are equivalent. In fact, you can prove it for the geometric series $\frac1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3...$.

Comment: Ok, I finaly understand. Thx a lot.